# In objective-c UISearchBar icon want to show left

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar

[image]

i want show my search icon at left side. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [UISearchBar reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/searchTextPositionAdjustment), One option is to use `- setPositionAdjustment:forSearchBarIcon:` to move the magnifying glass icon and to use `searchTextPositionAdjustment` property to make sure search text appears to the right of the icon.